# Atom keyboard shortcut to change window focus not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor, text-editor

I have the following `keymap.cson` file to config my Atom editor:

```
'body':
  'ctrl-shift-cmd-left': 'window:focus-pane-on-left'
```

Only when I run this command, the current text is selected.  Which without the alt key held, would make sense as a highlighting command.

However, is I bind a key command which I think most likely doesn't have a competing action, say `alt-cmd-;`, it seems to be registered into the list of key commands in `Settings/Keybindings`, yet again no window focus is happening.

## Edit:

I now realize that `pane` and not `window` may be the relevant term for what I want.  Still, searching the Key Bindings for pane focus switching didn't yield anything obvious.  Surely, there must be a simple  way to select through files in the `Project` area while editing.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer doesn't match the title of the question, based on your edit I think that **tree-view:toggle-focus** is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `Ctrl + 0`.

And, if you use `Nuclide` (related to React), please try disabling it to check the difference.